# How can I increase the speed of programm loading in windows

Tags: windows

How can I increase the speed of programm execution? The program with plug-ins is loaded about 40 seconds, but i needed to be not more than 5 sec. Can somehow cache files on hard disk, when they loadinng they will be taken from memory (from ram disk). I've read that there are windows have prefetcher and superfetch, but I have windows 2008 server operating system and there is no function. 
In the end I need to cache some files or a folder with files, so that when the query at the command line, they were loaded from ram disk

Comment: It's not even clear if this is just any program, or one you've developed yourself. In the first case, this question doesn't belong on this site, and in the second, this question is not near detailed enough.

Comment: More details please, like what is the development environment (which language/IDE/Framework is used to create that program and plugins), does that program connect to any database (and which one exactly), does it use network traffic and in what way, are all plugins loaded at program startup even if they are not used all the time? There are so many unknowns and so many conditions that can influence your software performance, so please provide as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code better. Debug and profile your application. Measure what is taking time in your application - and fix it. Parallel loading if possible.

Comment: sorry, but i mean any program, in my case it is 3d modeling program, i understand, this question doesn't belong on this site, anyway thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

Munch of the loading time for a .Net program can actually be compilation of your code. You can reduce this problem by pre-compiling your assemblies using a [tool called NGen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This must be run on the machine the application is to run on.

There are two other ways to reduce loading time. The first is to reduce the number of dependencies for your application. Replace external assemblies with smaller alternatives or even inline the code in your application. The second way is to look at the way you load your plugins. Is it possible to load them after your application has loaded? Maybe in a background task? This should help give your user the impression that the application loads faster.

Comment: You're assuming that said software has been developed in .NET, although OP has not provided such info.

Comment: Hehe. Yeah, you are right